# In vs. into? She's sprayed some vanilla into her mouth

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to ask a question about the use of *in* vs. *into*.

Which usage is more correct when I mean that she's sprayed some vanilla in her mouth and swallowed it?

> *She's sprayed some vanilla **in** her mouth.*
> *She's sprayed some vanilla **into** her mouth.*

In my mind, I picture the use of ***in*** as the center or the beginning of her mouth and ***into*** going beyond that, deep down her throat and to her stomach as if she's injected herself with it, putting an emphasis to the precision of doing it.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Have you checked this site for other "in vs. into" questions?

Answer (score 1):

If the direct object was let's say a medicine, the emphasis would fall on ***spray***, and the sentence would need to mark movement and direction so ***into*** would be better than ***in***.

There is no difference in how far in you get with *in* or *into*: *in* simply suggests *location, being in a larger space*, while *into* shows *specific movement and direction*:

> We use ***in*** to talk about where something is in relation to a larger area around it:
>
> - Jane is ***in*** the garden.
> - I’ve left my keys ***in*** the car.
>
> We use ***into*** to talk about *the movement of something, usually with a verb that expresses movement* (e.g. go, come). *It shows where something is or was going*:
>
> - Jane is gone ***into*** the house.
> - Helen came ***into*** the room. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/in-into))

With some verbs there is no ambiguity whether we use ***in*** or ***into***:

> With some verbs (e.g. ***put, fall, jump, dive***) we can use either ***in*** or ***into*** with no difference in meaning:
>
> - Can you put the milk ***in/into*** the fridge?
> - Her keys fell ***in/into*** the canal.

We could consider the verb ***to spray*** as belonging to this category, as in your sentence, it is used as a synonym of *put, place*, merely stating the manner in which she put vanilla in her mouth. The fact that the direct object is *vanilla* indicates that this is not a technical description of how a medicine is administered to her, but simply the way in which she places the vanilla in her mouth. The emphasis is more on *vanilla* than on *spray*. So your sentence would not need the technicality of ***into***:

> She's sprayed some vanilla ***in*** her mouth. (the vanilla is now in her mouth)

Comment: To “spray X in Y” can carry the idea that the spraying took place in Y. Spraying “into” doesn’t carry that connotation.

Comment: That explains it for me. Thank you!